# Node timing of a function in main thread and same host

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I have code like following in node process:

```
    setInterval(function updateRealtimeDataFromJsh() {
        console.time("update");
        <SOME synchronous JS execution>
        console.timeEnd("update");
    }, 1000);
```

Is it possible that time take by "update" can vary a lot i.e is it possible that sometime same js code is taking 10ms and some time it is taking 500ms, my understanding is that if node is able to execute this code it means main thread is free and every time it should take almost same time but it doesn't seem to be true, does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It depends on what else is taking up resources, what the "synchronous JS execution" is, …

Comment: synchronous JS execution is some code which merge two json.. so basically even if main thread is free CPU might be consumed by other threads in node process and it can cause delay? Other thread will not be using other CPU core?

Comment: Not necessarily other threads, but GC, other processes, JIT optimization and deoptimization…

Comment: In general above execution takes around 20-30 ms but if I trigger an another action which executes a js function periodically (this function do some processing in node main thread and compress data using node zlib), above execution starts taking around 300ms so I am wondering how come it becomes so worse as it will execute only when main thread will become free, is it because node zlib compression which is working in another thread and eating up cpu?